# Google Maps markers pop animation can't work

Tags: google-maps, swift3, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to make animation on google markers, here's my code :

```
let marker = GMSMarker()
            marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: long)
            marker.appearAnimation = GMSMarkerAnimation.pop
            marker.icon = UIImage(named: "marker-45")
            marker.title = titre
            marker.map = mapView
```

and this "GMSMarkerAnimation.pop" doesn't have any effect

What this animation should do? How can I do animation?

Comment: Nobody know ???

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the marker to the map later, for e.g. in `viewDidAppear`:

```
let marker = GMSMarker()

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    marker.map = mapView
}
```

Comment: The marker just appears on map normally, same as before, there's no pop on map